# How can function which has arguments be called without arguments

Tags: python

From the code below as you can see mysearch is called without arguments. How is this function call possible? How is it this technique called? Where does the method get it's argument (tag)? I'm sorry I can't find my answer anywhere...

```
def myserach(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('ResultsAd') # and tag['li']

with open('index.html', 'rb') as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, "html.parser")

elements1 = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "ResultsAd"})
elements1 = soup.find_all(myserach)
```

Comment: It *isn't* called in the parameters of find_all. It will be called inside body of find_all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is not called in your code snippet.

May be this example helps you understand better.

```
def foo(str):
    print(str)

def bar(arg):
    arg("now calling foo")

bar(foo)
```

Comment: Nice explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `elements1 = soup.find_all(my_search)` this line you're not calling `my_search`, you're passing `my_search` function to `soup.find_all` function.

Note: You can call functions without passing its arguments by using `keyword arguments`. Like:

```
def my_fun(value=5):
    print(value)
```

You can call this function in two ways:

```
my_fun(10) #here value will be 10
my_fun() #here value will be 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: IMHO you just went off topic with your edit. The case in the question has nothing to do with default parameters. A better choice would be an example of the structure you explained before, like e.g. in pandas `df.apply(sum)` or whatever

Comment: I think function calling without its arguments might help him to understand the topic. That's why I have added it. Thanks for your valuable opinion.

Comment: You're welcome and I agree that it's a topic which can and perhaps even should be mentioned additionally. But - imo - the requested case should be clarified as the main part in your answer.

Comment: As sjaymj62 explained nicely that's why I haven't added much explanation to my answers. I shall consider your opinion in my future answer. Lots of thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "calling a function", it's passing a function name (a function poiter in C terma) as argument to another function that later will call it with appropriate number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you are not calling the function. Function call without argument looks like `function()`. You don't give the `find_all` result of `mysearch` call, but the function itself. Then function can be called inside the `find_all`. These functions taking other functions as its parameters are called *Higher-order functions*. This is a example of a higher-order function:

```
def map(xs, f): 
  result = []
  for x in xs: 
    result.append(f(x))
  return result
```

So the idea is, that functions are just a values and the calling thing is just a method of them (`__call__`).